# Familiarizing with the Grothendieck topos $\mathbf{B}G$.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, topological-groups, topos-theory

I am trying to familiarize with the Grothendieck topos $\mathbf{B}G$ of continuous $G$-sets, where $G$ is a topological group.

I am unfortunately not very familiar with working with different topologies on groups; I am asking for a reference that covers topological group actions at a fairly elementary level - at a level that will allow me to understand the basic constructions needed in the topos. It would be ideal if the reference has a category-theory flavor. Thanks for any help!

Comment: All you need is the definition, and even then, only a special case. The objects in $\mathbf{B} G$ are the _discrete_ topological spaces $X$ equipped with a _continuous_ map $G \times X \to X$ that satisfies the usual group action axioms (but understood in $\mathbf{Top}$ rather than $\mathbf{Set}$).

Answer (score 5):

Mac Lane's and Moerdijk's *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* contains a section about that topos (III.9). It seems accessible without extended knowledge about continuous group actions.